# How to manage card box design in tree shape using HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to display the first card box in a single row, the second and third card box will be in the second row and the rest of all card boxes will be in the third row, using the same structure as the following code:

```css
.ranking-section {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
     }
     .ranking-section .card {
       border: none;
       width: 25%;
       float: left;
       padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .ranking-section .card:nth-child(-2n+4) {
      clear: both;
      page-break-after: always;
    }
    .card:nth-child(3n+4) {
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="elite-service-section ranking-section">
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">1</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="83, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">2</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="80, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">3</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="78, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">3</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="78, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">4</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="74, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">4</p>
            <div class="single-chart">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ebe8ef"></stop>
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6f8c6"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <path class="circle" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-dasharray="74, 100" d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
                    </svg>

                <img src="/Content/images/elite-service.png" class="elite-service-img" alt="elite Service">
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title p-t-10">Mohamed Said</h5>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

And rest of inside box design CSS didn't add because it's just simple common CSS.

**Note:** I don't want to manage using seprate row for three diffrent section.

So, anyone help on that how I can manage that?

[image]

Comment: so what you basically want is to access to the first, second and third item separately to modify their properties without creating a container for each section ?

Comment: yes, don't want to create a container for each section. I want to manage in a single common code as per the given HTML code.

Comment: So add the appropriate classes to those first three elements then. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: I have used dynamic content so, we can't add like that. as of now, I have shared static code. thanks for your suggestion